# UIScrollView in "U" shaped

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiscrollview

I want to know whether it is possible to create a scrollview that has a "U" shape or consisting of any other curvy patterns??

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [Custom Gesture Recognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) to recognize a "U".

It involves implementing the following methods:

```
- (void)reset;
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

and doing the geometry to find the pattern you are looking for.

Comment: basically i want the geometry, can u plz help me out :-s

Answer (score 0):

For rendering, probably some kind of transform layer could help. For touch processing, however, you probably are on your own.